# Getting notified when a JMenu is opened? (eg: File, Edit, View)

Tags: java, swing, events, jmenu

What I want to do is, when my Edit `JMenu` is clicked on, before it appears I want to set enabled on the undo / redo commands based on whether or not they should be visible.

Is there a way to get such a notification?  Is [`MenuListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MenuListener.html) what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a [MenuListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MenuListener.html), an extended `EventListener`, and enable the undo/redo items in `menuSelected`.

Now that I think about it, that probably would've been a better way for me to have done something very similar. I instead enabled/disabled the items in an `undo`/`redo` method in my view when my history object reported that there were no more undo/redo *commands* left.

**EDIT:** I see you must've quickly edited your post before I had the chance to post this and found `MenuListener` yourself.

Comment: That's okay, I still found your post helpful, Thanks :)